# Vue alternstive to react native an flutter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flutter, vue.js, native

I really enjoy using vue and nuxt. But I think mobile development or better "mobile and web development with the same code" is the future.

Is there a good way to use vue for that? Or should I switch gears?

There only seem to be flutter and react native. React did seem quite interesting on a first glance.

greetings

Comment: before your question gets closed as it is too broad and opinion based, you might have a look at NativeScript which is like React Native but you can select the language.

Answer (score 1):

Check `vue-native`

You can build cross platform apps based on JavaScript and Vue JS!

Comment: what?? there is vue-native ?

Comment: @ucup yeah (https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core)